# Ubuntu install freezes right after Grub "install Ubuntu" menu

Tags: grub2, system-installation, freeze, console, motherboard

I'm in the process of dual-booting Ubuntu 16.04 with Windows 10.

I seem to have an issue which might be related to my motherboard.

Using Rufus, I have created a bootable USB drive which I am trying to install Ubuntu from.

The issue arises when I boot the USB and proceed to click "install Ubuntu" from GRUB. What I can only assume is supposed to be a console freezes up and displays unreadable information as shown in the image attached.

Image of the frozen screen:

[image]

After crawling the web for a while I found another person with the same issue, but he had no responses on his post. What he did say though was that he had no problem using the same USB on another computer, figuring it is probably an issue with the motherboard. Some setting maybe. I have successfully installed Linux Mint on my computer before, so i'm unsure.

My Motherboard:

[image]

Anyone have any experience of have seen this issue before?

Edit 1: I added the "nomodeset" parameter in grub. Now "try ubuntu" option let me through to the desktop. A lot of "ACPI Error: namespace lookup failure" showed during boot though.

Comment: What happens if you select `Try Ubuntu` from the GRUB menu?

Comment: The same happens, unfortunately.

Comment: There may be a problem with your video card/drivers. Try booting in `Try Ubuntu` mode with the `nomodeset` parameter set. Have you checked for a BIOS update for your ASUS motherboard?

Comment: I added the nomodeset parameter and it let me through to the desktop in "try ubuntu" mode. Though it did show me a range of errors which i am unsure of "ACPI ERROR: Namespace lookup failure", before taking me to the desktop.

Comment: Progress! You'll probably need to add `nomodeset` to the `Install Ubuntu` menu choice also... but before that... check the version # of your BIOS and go to the manufacturer's web site and see if there's a new BIOS available. What video card do you have?  Ping me at `@heynnema` when you have more info, or I may miss any updates. Report back.

Comment: Thanks for the help @heynnema . It seems like using "nomodeset" into "try ubuntu", then proceeding to install from the trial desktop fixed the issue? Now i have dualbootet ubuntu, and when booting into the operating system everything works just fine. I tried googling to see what this "nomodeset" actually does, and it seems like it doesn't really affect anything but the splash-screen? My mobo had only a few stability fixes on Asus' website, and my graphics card is a Nvidia gtx970.

Comment: Glad you got it going. You still need to check/update the BIOS and the Nivida firmware. I don't think that you're at 100% yet with the ACPI error. I'll put together a quickie answer and maybe you can accept it if it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have anything in `/etc/default/grub` that resembles this `acpi_osi=Linux` in any way? Ping me at `@heynnema`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

Booting the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB required the use of the `nomodeset` parameter, which sets the video card up in its basic operation mode.

I believe that you should still check for a BIOS update for your motherboard, and firmware update for your Nvidia.

If you're still receiving ACPI errors, please start a new question for that.